# Unzip and stream an encrypted zip file using node.js

Tags: node.js, zip, unzip

I have an encrypted zip file on AWS S3 with one xml file inside. I am streaming that to my node.js heroku app and I need to unzip (with password) and stream the xml file through my SAX parser. I've got everything downpat with my SAX parser. The problem is getting the XML file out of the ZIP file using the password.

There seems to be plenty of decent libraries for node that allows you to unzip files. However, none of them support unzipping a zip file that is AES encrypted or encrypted period. At least, not to my find and I've spent a few hours researching this.

I would prefer to stream the zipfile and contents for sake of speed. Right now looks my only option I can find is to unzip the file via command line execution through node. I would not prefer to do this mainly because I can't find a way to stream the file via command line.

Comment: is this in a linux environment? you're familar with pipes? `unzip -c file | do_whatever` ? Good luck.

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a way to do this? How did you solve it in the end? I have a similar problem at the moment.

Comment: no solution yet?